# Revoke salesforce token nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth, salesforce

I am trying to revoke a salesforce token from `nodejs` using an `https request` (both `GET` and `POST` methods tried).

This is my code for `GET method`

```
var token = user.token;
var uri = token.instanceUrl+'/services/oauth2/revoke?token='+token.accessToken;
console.log("data: "+postData+", options: "+JSON.stringify(postOptions)+ ", \r\n" + uri);
https.get(uri, function(response){
    var buffer = '';
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        buffer += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log(buffer);
    });
});
```

But i keep on getting this

```
error=unsupported_token_type&error_description=this%20token%20type%20is%20not%20supported, code: 400
```

I have also tried the address in browser and get a `400 Bad Request` status.

All required options have been set according to salesforce online documentation https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_revoke_token.htm&language=en

What am I missing which makes it a bad request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm showing you how to do it using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module:

```
var request = require('request')
request.post('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/revoke', {
  form: {
    token: '[ACCESS_TOKEN]'
  },
  followAllRedirects: true
}, function (err, res, body) {})
```

No idea what URL you are trying with, but the login URLs are identical for all users, you don't have to use your instance subdomain.

Also note this from their docs:

> For a sandbox, use test.salesforce.com instead of login.salesforce.com.

Comment: i'll try this way. I am using instance URL because using login.salesforce.com return a 302 status code

Comment: same result, `statusCode: 400, body: 'error=unsupported_token_type&error_description=this%20token%20type%20is%20not%20supported'`

Comment: If you are sure you are passing the `access_token`, also note that the revoke method works only for OAuth2, so you have to make sure you are using the OAuth2 flow when logging in your users. Check out [here](https://grant-oauth.herokuapp.com/#/linkedin2) -- [Grant](https://github.com/simov/grant) supports both OAuth1.0 and OAuth2 flows for LinkedIn.

Comment: yes, using oauth2 and access_token. The point that I get same result when I access this address in browser means that it has to do something with salesforce or app setting. I have enabled the `Perform requests on your behalf at any time` permission. Do you have any idea if any specific settings/permissions are required to enable revocation?

Comment: Take a look at this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/v0AFW63.png), this is how a successful revoking looks like. Salesforce actually redirects you to your instance domain. If I execute the same code again, I get the same error as yours, so I assume your `access_token` have already been revoked. Also I updated my answer, you need to set one more request option - `followAllRedirects: true`

Comment: Your comment about the token being already invoked seems to solve the issue. Thanks for your efforts mate